# The hands of a clock are observed continuously from 12:45 pm onwards. They will be observed to point in the same direction some time between

Tags: recreational-mathematics

The hands of a clock are observed continuously from 12:45 pm onwards. They will be observed to point in the same direction some time between
A).1:03 pm and 1:04 pm
B).1:04 pm and 1:05 pm
C).1:05 pm to 1:06 pm
D).1:06 pm to 1:07 pm
I don't understand how to solve the question. Plz give proper explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we define the angle $\theta$ as zero when the hand is vertical and increasing clockwise, the minute hand is at $\theta=0$ at $1:00$ and the hour hand is at $\theta=\frac \pi 6$.  What is the angular speed of each hand?  Write an equation for the angle of each hand $t$ minutes after $1:00$.  Solve for when the angles are equal.

Comment: sorry! Still I am not able to solve..... every minute the minute hand goes 6 degree and the hour hand goes 1/2 degree ,so it is gaining on it by 5(1/2) degree per minute...........now what?? how to do it??

Comment: And the hour hand starts out $30$ degrees ahead, so it takes $\frac {30}{5\frac 12}$ minutes to catch up.

Comment: Now I get it........thnks a lot @Ross Millikan

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you have change in angle per minute $ v = 5.5°/min$, starting angle ${\varphi  }_{  1}$and final angle ${\varphi  }_{  2} = 0°$. You need to find time that is needed to get from ${\varphi  }_{  1}$ to ${\varphi  }_{  2}$.

Starting angle ${\varphi}_{1}$ is equal to sum of angles ${\alpha}_{1}$ and ${\alpha}_{2}$

Since time is 12:45, minute hand is pointed to 9. Angle between 9 and 12 ( ${\alpha}_{1}$) is $3 \cdot 30°$

${\alpha}_{1} = 90°$

Hour hand is on $\frac { 3 }{ 4 } $ of an hour from 12.

${\alpha}_{2} = \frac{3}{4} \cdot 30° =22.5° $

Angle between the minute and hour hand is sum of $\alpha_{1}$ and $\alpha_{2}$.

${\varphi_{1}=112.5°}$

[image]

Therefore,

$t=\frac{{\varphi}_{1}-{\varphi}_{2}}{v}$

$t=\frac{112.5°}{5.5°/min}=20.454\quad min$

Your answer is then 12:45 + 20.454 $min$ = 13:05:27

Comment: woah man! It has become complicated........ plzzzz anyone solve it for me .

Comment: @matrikashukla
I edited my answer. I hope you understand it now.

Comment: wooooow! (jaw dropping) ...........love u for the explanation! @David buzgo